# Disable Buttons in AR SceneKit Swift

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

I need the buttons to be disabled on top of Scene objects. How can i achieve that? The current code i am working is working fine but how can i get a specific child node to be transparent,

```
extension SCNMaterial {
    convenience init(color: UIColor) {
        self.init()
        diffuse.contents = color
    }
    convenience init(image: UIImage) {
        self.init()
        diffuse.contents = image
    }
}

let clearMaterial = SCNMaterial(color: .clear)
boxNode.materials = [clearMaterial]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you not get any error? `SCNGeometry` not `SCNNode` have material. try:

```
boxNode.geometry?.materials = [clearMaterial]
```

I tried this but it did not work. Maybe `SCNMaterial` cant use `.clear`

I have always used `.transparency` to hide/unhide node. try this:

```
func show(){
    yourNode.geometry?.firstMaterial?.transparency = 1
}

func hide(){
    yourNode.geometry?.firstMaterial?.transparency = 0
}
```

Comment: i tried this approach of changing materials to `.clear` and it didnot work.